# Oracle Package Error

Tags: oracle, package

I want to create a package and inside the package we have a function having a parameter. I have table for TIME_DIM and the granularity of that table is one record/second. I am getting an error while crating this package any one help me on this.

```
create or replace
PACKAGE PKG_TIME_DIM
IS
 Function FUN_TIME_DESC
   ( TIME_IN IN varchar2 )
   RETURN varchar2
IS
   TIMEDESC varchar2;
   CURSOR c1
   IS
     SELECT TIME_DESC
     from TIME_DIM
     where TIME_DESC = TIME_IN;
BEGIN
   open c1;
   fetch c1 into TIME_DESC;
   if c1%notfound then
      TIMEDESC := 9999;
   end if;
  close c1;
RETURN TIMEDESC;
END;
END;
```

Comment: Another [new account](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17678660/266304)? You don't seem to have got the hang of providing the information people need to help you.

Comment: TIMEDESC varchar2; facing error here.
Error(7,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TIMEDESC" when expecting one of the following:     language

Answer (score 2):

i don't know what error do you get but i see sevral problems:
by the  declaration of the TIMEDESC variable the size of varchar2 is missing:
for Example:  `TIMEDESC varchar2(2000);` or better

```
TIMEDESC TIME_DIM.TIME_DESC%TYPE;
```

there is a tipo in the following statment

```
fetch c1 into TIME_DESC;
```

you have declarated `TIMEDESC` and not `TIME_DESC` as the name of the variable

and may be the following is a problem

```
TIMEDESC := 9999;
```

TIMEDESC  is of type varchar but you assigning number to it

Answer (score 2):

There are many errors here. You appear to be declaring a package specification with code in it. You need both a specification and body. I've added comments on each line that had an issue:

```
-- Note: "CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE" = The specification
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TIME_DIM
IS

    FUNCTION FUN_TIME_DESC (TIME_IN IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2;

END PKG_TIME_DIM;
/

-- Note: "CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY" = Keyword BODY = the body
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TIME_DIM
IS
    FUNCTION FUN_TIME_DESC (TIME_IN IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
        TIMEDESC  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR); -- Need to define length of this variable in characters or bytes

        CURSOR c1 IS
          SELECT TIME_DESC
            FROM TIME_DIM
           WHERE TIME_DESC = TIME_IN;
    BEGIN
        OPEN c1;
        FETCH c1 INTO TIMEDESC; -- Changed variable name to match the name you defined

        IF c1%NotFound THEN
            TIMEDESC := '9999'; -- Put quotes around this since this is a VARCHAR
        END IF;

        CLOSE c1;

        RETURN TIMEDESC;

    END FUN_TIME_DESC;

END PKG_TIME_DIM;
/
```

Comment: Thanks wweicker Still I am getting an error "Error(9,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:     end function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior"

Comment: @SteveSmith oops I made a typo with "END PACKAGE PKG_TIME_DIM;" instead of "END PKG_TIME_DIM;" - try again

Comment: @wweicker - I think the error 'Steve' got was from not having a `/` after the `END PKG_TIME_DIM;` lines. SQL Developer will see that all as one command. (And SQL*Plus won't like it either).

Comment: You guts are Awesome. Thanks a lot Wweicker & Alex